# LOAD DATA INFILE in Unix

Tags: unix

I have a script that will load a file to my mysql db:

```
for file in files

do

source=$file
gunzip $source
source1=${file%*.*} #remove the gz extension

#connect to database
mysql --host=localhost --user=user --password=password mydb << EOF
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE $source1 INTO TABLE mytable;
EOF

done
```

I keep on getting this error:

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'file.txt INTO TABLE mytable' at line 1

Is there a problem with my script? Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file name must be enclosed into single quotes, as required by the [syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html) of the `LOAD DATA FILE` command.

Hence you could try something like (untested):

```
for file in files
do

    source=$file
    gunzip $source
    source1=${file%*.*} #remove the gz extension

    #connect to database
    mysql --host=localhost --user=user --password=password mydb << EOF
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$source1' INTO TABLE mytable;
EOF

done
```

Comment: It's working now. So the single quote is needed, I thought you just put it if the filename is fixed. Thanks!

Comment: So, would you please mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the little gray arrow above the big 0? :)

Comment: Is it possible to do the same thing avoiding write uncompressed $source1 to disk?

Comment: I ended up creating a ramdisk in my script and `pigz -dc > $ramdisk` the files I needed to import.